# Writing Gmail Chrome Extesion

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail

I'm interesting in developing Chrome Extension for Gmail.
Unfortunately I couldn't find any tutorials on this subject (demonstrating a simple action as adding a button).
I'm looking for adding a button to the compose toolbar, and creating a new tag/folder in gmail account.

Please, Help!

Answer (score 1):

You should check out these APIS at https://github.com/joscha/gmailr, it is a fork of https://github.com/jamesyu/gmailr but the original author has been too busy to update it.